# WCF ServiceHost gets restarted unexpectedly everyday at 1pm

Tags: wcf

My WCF Web Service is hosted by IIS 7 in WinServer 2008. I configured the AppPool to recycle at 1am and 8pm, but not 1pm, though the ServiceHost is restarted every day 1pm according to WCF service trace.

[AppPool Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t4AZ.png)

It doesn't always cause issues, when it takes only about 1 minute to restart. But it sometimes takes around 30 minutes to restart, which causes connection timeout error in client side.

[Trace for restarting causing timeout error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnLH8.png)

I checked windows event log, there's recycling log for app pool restarting at 1 am and 8 pm but never 1 pm. I do understand App Pool restarts in some error situations, but it doesn't seem to apply in my situation. It seems that it's a configuration somewhere which I'm oblivious at. Please help.

Comment: I added following into web.config, but it didn't seem to work. Is it just for .net 2.0? I'm using .net4.0.

<add name="Application Lifetime Events Default" 
     eventName="Application Lifetime Events" 
     provider="EventLogProvider" 
     profile="Default" 
     minInstances="1" 
     maxLimit="Infinite" 
     minInterval="00:01:00" 
     custom="" />

Comment: By the way, the recycling of app pool I configured in IIS doesn't show up in event trace, but only in windows event viewer.